# Similar Columns Relation in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework-4

I use Entity Framework 4 on C# Winforms.

I have a SQL Server database with 2 tables like this:

`Users` table:

```
UserId (int) (PK)
UserName
```

`Products` table:

```
ProductId (int)(PK)
ProductTitle
UserId1 (int) (foreign key referencing `UserId` in `Users` table)
UserId2 (int) (foreign key referencing `UserId` in `Users` table)
```

I am modeling SQL Server database in my C# project with Entity Framework (including foreign key columns in model).

Then I get records with this code:

```
Entities dbEnteties = new Entities();
dbEnteties.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
var dbe = dbEnteties.Products.Include("Users");
var result = dbe.ToList();
```

When I get records from database I see that the `UserId1` field has data but `UserId2` field is `Null`.

What's wrong with my C# code? And how can I solve this problem?!

Comment: Why you have two foreign keys referencing Users Table?

Comment: user1 for something & user2 for something else. i need to have 2 columns.
for example user1 create a product and user2 update product

Comment: So, you want to achieve many to many relationship between the two tables? Or one Product to have many Users?

Comment: I think you should remove `UserId2 (int) (foreign key referencing UserId in Users table)` and make a `virtual ICollection<User>` in your entity `Product` class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's perfectly okay for you to have two foreign keys in the Products table pointing to the Users table.  I do this all the time, and your reason for doing it is fine.

Since you have turned Lazy Loading off, you need to explicitly ".Include" the navigation properties if you want the query to automatically load them.  You're going to have to figure out what the names are for the navigation properties that Entity Framework created automatically for you.  I'm assuming you are using the "Database First" model.  If that's the case, then double click on your .EDMX file and look at the Products table.  You should see a section there called "Navigation Properties".  They might be called "User" and "User1".  If this is the case, then you need to do the following.  Since you have two separate relationships between the tables, you will need two separate ".Include" statements:

```
            dbEnteties.Products.Include(product => product.User);
            dbEnteties.Products.Include(product => product.User1);
```

(Make sure to include **using System.Data.Entity;** at the very top of your file, otherwise the lambda syntax will not work.)

Comment: thanks, it's work
i use this code and work's fine:
dbEnteties.Products.Include("Users").Include("Users1");